# Upload using angular-file-model and rest_framework

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, django-rest-framework

Got error

```
The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.
```

My code looks like follow:

Model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('Date'))
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, verbose_name=_('Project'), related_name='projects')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Document Type'))
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, verbose_name=_('Document'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

My code for serializer:

```
class DocumentSaveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('name', 'date', 'project', 'type', 'docfile')
```

My views:

```
class DocumentViewSet(WithNestedSerializerMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
    queryset = Document.objects.all()

    get_object_serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
    post_serializer_class = DocumentSaveSerializer
    put_serializer_class = DocumentPutSerializer

    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
```

And some code from frontend:

```
Directive: cmsApp.directive(
    'contracts',
    [
        'ContractService',
        '$rootScope',
        function (ContractService, $rootScope) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    contract: '=',
                    projectId: '=',
                    typeId: '=',
                    docFile: '='
                },
                templateUrl: 'main/templates/contract.html',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.newContract = function(){
                    scope.contract.document.project = scope.projectId;
                    scope.contract.document.type = scope.typeId;
                    scope.contract.document.docfile = scope.docFile;
                    ContractService.createContract(scope.contract)
                    scope.contract.document = {};
                };
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

And finally HTML:

```
<input type="file" file-model="docfile">

<span ng-if="DocumentName == 'Contract'" contracts contract="Contract" project-id="ProjectID" type-id="DocumentName" doc-file="docfile"></span>
```

Dont have any ideas what is wrong with this code. Anny suggestions? File is loaded properly. I test it with showing name, size etc. But when i try to POST i've got an error I mentioned at the benning.

Thanks for help

Comment: did you add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you are submitting your file via form, you need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your `<form>` tag

Otherwise, if you are using `$http` angular service, you need add this header.

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
```

It should looks like this:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/your_post/url',
   data: data_with_your_file// your original form data,
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
}).
```

**BUT**

I highly recommend using [angular-file-upload.js](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload files in angular. Is very clean, I use it with DRF too.

Comment: got something like this:
return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: {contract: newContract.document.docfile}, // your original form data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
            })

But now I have error 500

Comment: @bMh 500 error, is server error, check your server logs.